# SSIS import Excel formula in sql server

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I'm pretty new in SSIS and i'm trying again to convert my excel document in a sql server table.

Here is the problem of my excel file, it has multiple sheet but this was solved with SSIS.

But here is the content i can find :

Column B2 content "=-16,2-81-25-130-75" and so Excel shows -327.2
With ssis i correctly succeed to import the value -327.2 but what i would like is to read the "=-16.2......" as a text and then transform it.

I'm looking in the properties but i cannot find, i don't even know if it's possible, what i would like to avoid is to transform all my columns in the excel file.... it's a file with 60 sheets and each times with around 100 columns. i would prefer to automate instead of update 6000 cells.

I thought using a vba in excel to transform this too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult one because SSIS was not meant for this. But I think I found a way for you to do that. Here's the step I followed:

1. In Excel, [File],[Options],[Advanced],[Display options for this worksheet] then check [Show formulas in cells instead of their calculated results]
2. Save your sheet in a CSV file. Check this file. You should see your formula.
3. Use DTSWizard to import this new file.
4. Do that again 60 times or create a macro.